# Cannot share wslg stuff in skype

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, screen-sharing, skype-for-windows-10, windows-11-v23h2, wslg

When in a skype conversation, I have a wslg window open (with emacs running there) and want to share it. When I invoke screen sharing I am presented with a choice of buttons corresponding to sharing separate currently open windows or the entire screen. The wslg window option is blacked out, with the text telling that it cannot be shared. If I share entire screen, it works and at the other end of the conversation they can see that window too, but after several seconds the skype session becomes disconnected.

The same happens with any other wsl windows.

Did anybody else encounter this issue? Can it be resolved somehow?

Windows 22631.3374
Skype 8.115.0.217
WSL 2.1.5.0 with Ubuntu 23.10
Kernel 6.1.21.2-microsoft-standard-WSL2+
WSLg 1.0.60